# Panel data where some variables might have a curved relation on the dependent variable

Tags: r, regression, binomial-distribution, panel-data

I have dataset of panel data which includes companies over time. See the image below to see how it's formatted. I believe there might be a inverted u-curve relationship on the different diversity variables on `MarketCapital` – i.e. too little and too much diversity might be negative on market capital while somewhere in the middle might be good.

[image: Panel Data]

I have so far done a panel data regression in R using the following code:

```
fixed<-plm(
        MarketCapital ~
        #Independent Variables:
          Experience
        + PatentQuality
        + CompanyDiversity
        + IndustryDiversity
        + PatentDiversity
        #Control Variables:
        + MarketAge
        + CompanyAge
        + Industry
        + Country
        + MarketAge
        + CompanyAge
        + CompanyPatents
        + Inventors
        + StarInventors
        + RnDExpenditure
        + RnDIntensity
        + Employees
        + Revenue
        + factor(Year)
        , data=PanelData, index=c("Company","Year"), model="within")
```

How would I go about it testing a u-curve relationship on all of the Diversity variables? Does anyone have an idea or a direction to point me towards? Appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You could look into fractional polynomials (in R see the mfp package), or fit (restricted) cubic splines (in R see the rms package).

Comment: So simply transforming the diversity variables within the `plm` function is the correct way to do it, if I understand your suggestion correctly @IWS?

Comment: I do not know the plm function (can't find it in R base), but if its transformations you're after look into the mfp package (with a modelfitting function  using the same name which supports different types of regression). If it's a spline you want to deal with non-linearity, you'd want look into the rms package, where the amongst others the rcs function can be used inside of different regression models in order to fit a non-linear association.